# \NewDocumentCommand with delimited arguments

Tags: macros, xparse

How can the following command be implemented with `\NewDocumentCommand`?:

```
\def\bracket<#1|#2>{
    \left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\bracket<#1|#2>{
    \left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\NewDocumentCommand\bracket{}{\brackethelp}
\def\brackethelp<#1|#2>{\left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle}` qualify?

Comment: Why not use normal arguments? Do you think `\bracket<\phi|\phi>` looks that much clearer than `\bracket{\phi}{\phi}`? Also, please note that there is a package for braket notation named `braket`, maybe you want to give it a try instead fo reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Skillmon I want it that way, that's my answer.

Comment: Then this is not really supported by `\NewDocumentCommand`, the whole idea of it is to implement standard argument types, all the more exotic ones are discouraged, better stick to `\def`, imho, maybe add an `\@ifdefinable\racket` to ensure the macro doesn't conflict with things. Also, in `braket` the syntax would be something like `\braket{\phi|\phi}`, not too far off from yours, but way more LaTeXy.

Comment: Why `\NewDocumentCommand`? There is, e.g., epl3's `\cs_new_protected:Npn
`...

Comment: `\left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle` does not ensure the < and > have the same size which is rather weird. why not `\left\langle #1 \middle| #2 \right\rangle` ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make IMHO not really sense, but if you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{r<|}{%
  \typeout{TRACE1: \detokenize{#1}}%
  \@bracket{#1}|%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@bracket}{mr|>}{%
  \left\langle #1\middle|#2\right\rangle
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

or with one macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{e{<}r|>}{%
  \left\langle #1\middle|#2\right\rangle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But IMHO better would be something like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{r<>}
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { | } { #1 }
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \left\langle \l_tmpa_tl
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \middle | ##1 }
    \right\rangle
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \bracket<\phi|\phi>
  \bracket<\phi>
  \bracket<>
  \bracket<\phi|\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

or easier:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{r<>}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { | } { \middle | }
    \left\langle \l_tmpa_tl \right\rangle
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \bracket<\phi|\phi>
  \bracket<\phi>
  \bracket<>
  \bracket<\phi|\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Both result in:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Trust me: you don't want automatic sizing. Just look at the last two examples.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{s O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}r<>}{%
  % #1 = optional * for \left and \right
  % #2 = optional size command \big \Big ...
  % #3 = the main argument (required to be in <>)
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% automatic sizing
    \mleft\langle\makebracket{\;\middle|\;}#3\mright\rangle
  }{% no automatic sizing
    \mathopen{#2\langle}\makebracket{\mathrel{#2|}}#3\mathclose{#2\rangle}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makebracket}{mmm}{%
  % #1 = middle delimiter
  % #2 = before |
  % #3 = after | (if present)
  #2 \IfValueT{#3}{#1 #3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\bracket<a> \\
\bracket<a|b> \\
\bracket[\big]<a> \\
\bracket[\big]<a | b> \\
\bracket[\bigg]<\sum_{k=1}^n a_k | x> \\
\bracket*<\sum_{k=1}^n a_k | x>
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Note: `twocolumn` is just to make a smaller picture.

The optional and required arguments (the last one delimited inside `<>`) are preprocessed and control is then passed to `\makebracket` that typesets the inner part.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In general, `ltcmd` is intended for providing 'regular' LaTeX syntax, although it does allow some more flexible forms. Here, I would read the request as a *require* delimited argument which is split into two parts: similar to picture mode `(..,..)` in that sense:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\bracket{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}} R<>{|}}
  {\bracketaux#1}
\newcommand*\bracketaux[2]{\left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This is not an answer to the question of how to do it using `\NewDocumentCommand` from ltcmd/xparse.]

I might probably not bother using ltcmd/xparse at all.

Instead of `\def` I might probably just use expl3's `\cs_new_protected:Npn`; this way the command is protected in some expansion-contexts and you get a message in case defining implies overriding a definition already provided.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn\bracket<#1|#2>{\left\langle#1\middle|#2\right\rangle}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way (don't know, if there is a better way):

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\NewDocumentCommand{\bracket}{e<d|>}{
    \left\langle #1 \right|\left. #2 \right\rangle
}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \bracket<\phi|\phi>
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bracket<\phi^2|\phi>`  breaks silently. `\bracket |\phi>` also doesn't yield an error message.